# What are possible options for creating searchable select inputs in a Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I'm trying to avoid using jQuery, and thus, looking for alternatives to Select2 for creating searchable select inputs in a Rails app.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the options I've been recommended by now are [Choices](https://github.com/jshjohnson/Choices) and [Slim Select](https://slimselectjs.com/).

Answer (score -1):

According to [alternativeto.net](https://alternativeto.net/software/select2/), [tail.select](https://github.com/pytesNET/tail.select) and [selectr](https://github.com/Mobius1/Selectr) (no active development) uses vanilla JS.